# How can I add an additional binding to an element inside a dom-repeat?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a template dom-repeat element.  I know that I can define the `items` attribute from an array, so that `item` can be accessed inside the template.  However, I don't know how to access other objects inside the template if I bind them to customer polymer elements.

In this example, `items` is being defined by `someItems`, and `item` is passed into the element `<my-el>`.  I also have a string `mine` that I want to pass into `<my-el>` and use there.  I currently have the idea to do this in app-el.html, which contains the dom-repeat template:

#### app-el.html

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[someItems]]">
  <my-el item=[[item]] mine="[[mine]]"></my-el><br>
</template>
```

In theory, I would be able to access both in my-el.html like this:

#### my-el.html

```
[[item]] [[mine]]
```

However, when I try to access `mine` from inside `<my-el>` it is undefined.  How can I correctly pass in this string so I can access it?

An MCVE can be found on this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8LPlwWBBCVfRcVfIklz1?p=preview).  Note how the `item` string is defined inside `<my-el>` but the `mine` string is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data bindings look correct, but there is no `mine` property for `my-app`. Did you mean to define `<my-app>.myProperty` as `<my-app>.mine`? Changing that property name to `mine` fixes your problem.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Trz7xtOsasWozqcVZeFz?p=preview)

Comment: Darn, I was sure it was more involved than that.  I just happened to make exactly the same mistake in my MCVE as in my production code -.-